# check if element exists after ajax load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

It's Friday morning and my brain appears to be malfunctioning.

I would like to execute a load of script, but only when a certain element is present on the page. This may have also been loaded via ajax. Which means when I do something like:

```
if ($('#foo').length > 0) {
    // Do stuff
});
```

It will only load on direct page loads, not ajax... obviously. I just can't think of the how to trigger this check after an ajax load.

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

You can do a check after every AJAX request by using [`ajaxComplete`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/):

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    if ($('#foo').length) {
        // do stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: This seems to work well apart from on one of my ajax calls - I get a successful result, a lightbox is loaded but still nothing from `$(document).ajaxComplete(function() { alert('test'); });` ?

Comment: @Colin Perhaps the request disabled the global handlers using `global: false` in the original AJAX request?

Comment: Hmm no that doesn't seem to be it. It's the same ajax request with variable url called on form submit, which brings up the next section of the form in a lightbox. The first call results in `$(document).ajaxComplete(function() { alert('test'); });` working, the following calls, although successfull (loading the next section of the form to the lightbox on ajax success), don't seem to trigger ajaxComplete.

Comment: @Colin Are the lightbox contents in an iframe? Could you provide a link?

Comment: I don't think the lightboxs are iframes, no. They are created using https://github.com/premasagar/nitelite jqeury plugin - called by a fairly standard ajax call - `$.ajax({ type: 'POST',url: url, dataType: 'json', data: post, success: function(data) { lightbox(data.title, data.content, data.classes, data.url, exit, transition, traversal); });`

Comment: @Colin I mean a link to your non-functioning page.

Comment: I'd love to give you one but I can't. I know that's not very helpful.