# how to check if ajax call add content to an element

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've already read this: [check if element exists after ajax load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5675085/check-if-element-exists-after-ajax-load) but i can't fix my issue.

An ajax call put contents (a list) into a div if some server side checks were done, if checks fail no contents will put..

The ajax call puts into a div (#sims) an :

```
$.post({
    data: {'data': data},
    dataType: 'html',
    url: 'myurl.php',
    success: function (result){
        $('#sims').html(result);
    }
});
```

HTML (after ajax):

```
<div id="sims">
    <div id="sim_ul">
        <ul>
            <li>some content</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

After ajax call this if is false, why:

```
if ($('#sim_ul').lenght > 0)
   // do some stuffs
```

I should check if #sim_ul exists and then add other content to my page..

Please help me.

Comment: Have you tried `if ($('#sim_ul').children().size() > 0)`?

Comment: if you add the `sim_ul` div dinamically you should use delegated events (`.on`) to access the element. it is not present on document ready. You can use a workaround an add only the ul keeping from the beginning the container div.

Comment: Thank your answer works well (like my .lenght solution). The problem is due to the asyncronous, I guess. Because if i type an: alert('some alert') this works, is this related to prevent default? And if yes, how to workaround it?

Comment: if ($('#sim_ul').lenght > 0) here spellings missing. Correct it first like this if ($('#sim_ul').length > 0) first and check.

Comment: I solved that putting if check into $('#sim_ul').ready() function